# C Increase struct value

Tags: c, struct

I was asked to create a program where the user could add cars and I would have to save the car's brand, color, and so on. Then I have to display them, and display the ones with more sales, all that. I thought about creating a structure and saving everything there, the problem is, I don't know how many cars the user will input.

How can I dynamically increase the structure saved values? I wanted to do something like:

```
 struct car{
        int Bhp;
        char Brand[25];
        char color[25];
        int sales;
        float weight;
                      };
```

and then:

```
  struct car car1;
  struct car car2;
```

but I would have to dynamically increase the number of "cars" as the user would add more and more. Is there any way I could do that? And please explain it in a simple way, as I am still a C beginner. Thank you very much.

Comment: Read about pointers, `malloc`, and *flexible array members*

Comment: I was saying I am having classes, like...learning C. I know that there are no classes in C. We are talking about different things ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun `There is no classes in C` Seriously?! I think i read something else.

Comment: @al-Acme That's why I wrote *classes* (italic). There's not `class` keyword. I prefer to not say "classes" when I talk in C language.

Comment: @al-Acme, the post was edited.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple and you are certain you have a MAXIMUM number of cars.  Just define a large array of them and keep a separate counter to indicate how many are in use.  I prefer simplicity if possible.

Comment: @Mykod Have you seen this [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `malloc()` initially:

```
struct car *p = malloc(sizeof(struct car);
```

Now you can add one car detail. Now if you want to increase the number of car's then use `realloc()` and allocate larger memory based on number of car details you are going to add.

```
struct car *temp = realloc(p,sizeof(struct car) *n);

if(temp != NULL)
p = temp;
```

Check code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
 struct car{
        int Bhp;
        char Brand[25];
        char color[25];
        int sales;
        float weight;
        };

int main(void) {
    int n;
    struct car *temp = NULL;
    struct car *p =  malloc(sizeof(struct car));
    p->Bhp = 100;
    strcpy(p->Brand,"audi");
    strcpy(p->color,"red");
    p->sales = 200;
    p->weight = 250.90;
    printf("%d %s %s %d %5.2f\n",p->Bhp,p->Brand,p->color,p->sales,p->weight);
    printf("Enter number of cars\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    temp = realloc(p,sizeof(struct car) *(n+1));
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Reallocation failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    p = temp;
        p[1].Bhp = 100;
    strcpy(p[1].Brand,"benz");
    strcpy(p[1].color,"green");
    p[1].sales = 300;
    p[1].weight = 240.90;
    printf("%d %s %s %d %5.2f\n",p[1].Bhp,p[1].Brand,p[1].color,p[1].sales,p[1].weight);
    // The rest of the data can be filled similarly
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I kind of understand what you are trying to say. I create a pointer to the structure, allocate memory to it. But I don't understand the second part. Is there any way you can show me an example of it being implemented? I'm so sorry, but I am still learning and I have an exam this week...thank you so much.

Comment: @Mykod The second part is basically increasing the already allocated memory. `realloc()` does it for you. As you know your pointer is pointing to some memory location you pass that location to `realloc() ` and ask it to increase the existing memory by some amount.So increasing the allocated memory makes sure that you get extra memory to add new cars. `realloc()` might fail so use some `temp` to store the return value and check it before assigning it back to your original pointer

Comment: and what does the _if(temp !=NULL) p=temp;_ do ?

Comment: @Mykod Checks the return value of `realloc()` There is a possibility that `realloc()` might fail and return NULL so that is handled like this. Check the return value and if it is not NULL then assign it back to your pointer which you used initially to do `malloc()`. You need to use the right value while reallocating so that the new memory chunk can hold both the initial data as well as the new data that is going to be added

Answer (score 3):

Just do it this way, first declare `n`, it will be the count of elements in the array of `car`'s

```
int n;
```

and initialize it

```
n = 0;
```

now declare a pointer

```
struct car *car = NULL;
```

now say you have `1` `car`, then assign `1` to `n`, and

```
struct car *temp = realloc(car, n * sizeof(struct car));
if (temp != NULL)
    car = temp;
```

now you can access the `n-th` element with `car[n - 1]`, the first element is `car[0]`, so you have to subtract one. After that increase `n` if there are more `car`'s and then when you are done using it just `free(car)`.

You don't need the first `malloc` because when you pass `NULL` to `realloc` it behaves like `malloc`.

Comment: Oh, I really fell like a noob now. I understand pointers, structures and I know what malloc is, but I don't understand how to implement your code...

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: 1) I don't know what NULL does in this case
2) I still don't know do I implement the number of cars in the structures
3) I don't understand what the variable temp and n do...
Seriously, I'm still learning the basics of C, and you guys are pros,I'm sorry..

Comment: `n` is the count of cars you already have, `NULL` is an invalid address `(void *)0x00` it is useful to now if your pointer points somewher or not, `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` functions all return `NULL` on failure, so you must check the return value, in the case of `realloc` you check it before reassigning the original pointer, in many cases `temp` and `car` would actually be the same even without `car = temp` but not always, so you need to be sure.

Comment: but where is the variable n declared?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to do this is is using a *pointer-to-structure* and *dynamic memory allocation*.

1. Take a pointer of type `struct car`, sat `struct car *cp = NULL;`
2. For the first time, allocate memory using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to that pointer for one object of type `struct car`.
3. From next time onwards, use [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) on `cp` with `(n * sizeof (struct car))`, where `n>=2`. Increment `n` each time you want to add an instance of `struct car`.

Note:

1. While using this approach, at the end, you need to `free()` up the memory you've allocated dynamically.
2. don't forget to check the success of `malloc()`/ `calloc()`/`realloc()` before using the pointer returned by those calls.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the realloc for allocating the memory as dynamically.

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

You can [Refer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) this or else [this.](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)